# const T& vs. T&&

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have the following function:

```
T foo();
```

And, in another function, I'm playing with the returned `T` value, like:

```
const T& t = foo();
```

or

```
T&& t = foo();
```

I want to ask:

1. Are both equivalent?
2. Memory-wise, what are the difference between these two approaches?
3. I know that on the first approach the temporary value lifetime matches the reference lifetime. The same occurs when using the rvalue reference?
4. Should I even consider using a const rvalue reference (`const T&&`)?

I'm using the first approach, that is what I'm used to and attends me fine. I'm still wrapping my head around rvalue references and C++11 goods.

Comment: Just because you can make a local rvalue reference variable doesn't mean it's useful.  They are mainly intended for parameters, and occasionally return values.

Comment: Is `T` a deduced type or not? That makes a big difference.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Good point.  I think this question intends that `T&&` actually is an r-value reference, not subject to reference collapsing rules.

Comment: @sftrabbit: It doesn't have to be a *deduced* type, I think. As long as it's a *dependent* type then it can cause a problem: http://ideone.com/49b9HZ

Comment: when the function result can be a subclass of the result variable's static type, use a reference. that way you avoid slicing, by way of some special language support. however, the only use case i know of is the orginal c++03 scopeguard implementation, so most likely there is no reason to use a reference in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, they have different types.
2. Implementation-defined, but there's unlikely to be any difference.
3. Lifetime extension works the same for rvalue and lvalue references.  But the rule is more complicated than "the temporary value lifetime matches the reference lifetime".
4. Probably not.  I certainly wouldn't go looking for places to use it.  If you have a use for it, it had better be such an significant improvement to justify the use of such an unusual combination and the confusion that will ensue when people read it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. They are basically the same (lifetime extension of temporaries applies) but one is `const` and one is not.
2. There probably isn't any difference "memory-wise" but that's implementation-dependent.
3. Yes.
4. I can't imagine a case where you'd want that.

However, move-semantics really make the technique you're using antiquated. It was originally intended to let people avoid making unnecessary copies, but now with move semantics, what would be expensive before is now practically free and much more readable.

Comment: Re: 'Move semantics make this antiquated': If `T` has a proper move assignment operator, you can simply write `T t = foo();` without there being any unnecessary copies, right?

Comment: @us2012 no, in `T t = foo()` the assignment operator is unrelated. It would be the move-constructor. However, the compiler will probably elide even that, so that not even a move takes place.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever wondered when and if to use &&, I strongly recommend watching

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11

Imho, it's definitly worth investing the time.

To my understanding:

1+2) Depends on the type of T

3) No impact on lifetime off the referenced value. Side note : whatever **T&&** ends up to be type wise, it's got a name now: **t**, and therefore is an l value.

4) Kind of directed towards myself: How do you move from something that's const?

Best Jochen

edit: added blank lines.